# Проблема с Microsoft SQL Server на Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

Сделал не большой сайт с БД на Visual Studio 2013. Теперь хотел открыть ее на Visual Studio 2015. Но вводится ошибка как на скрине. Как можно исправить эту ошибку? Будьте добры, помогите! Буду благодарен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы использовали подключение к SQL server или подключение к файлу базы данных?

Comment: к файлу базу данных

Comment: ок, а у вас есть возможность сделать скрин из VS 2013 того же подключения? обычно создают подключение к SQL Server для использования БД

Comment: вот скрин https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5Qjy/4WviTFEyE

Comment: ну, как там????

Comment: я в общем понял, что вы пользуетесь подключением к файлу, вместо подключения к sql server -  в данном случае помочь не могу, не было необходимости вести так разработку

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio искал этот источник данных: LocalDB. Ее не было в VS 2015.

LocalDB является опцией при установке любого SKU SQL Server 2012 Express. Выберите LocalDB на странице выбора функций во время установки SQL Server Express.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо LocalDB можно найти здесь: [скачать](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом указываем LocalDB на DataSource

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите суть поста по ссылке прямо в текст ответа

Comment: Скорее всего можно сформулировать вопрос не как проблемы со скулем , а проблемы со знаниями . при переходе с версии студии на версию студии . Это естественное положение вещей ...